# Understanding Bash Scripting

Tags: python, bash

I am very much new Bash world. I am working in a project where I came across an external program pluggin and they have a command like this

```
bash -l -c "/usr/local/bin/python /opt/abc/abcd/test.py --user {username} --password {password} {inputFileLuid0} {prLuid}"
```

I am not able to understand what the -l and -c stands here for. Also we have two directory locations. Please help m with this.

Comment: Run `man bash` from the terminal to see the manual page for `bash`. The first path is the path to the python interpreter, the second path is the path to the file.  You can read this as saying "start a new copy of bash, then run `python test.py`" https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: Also don't use such a command line without thinking twice because the user name and password may well stay in the bash history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page `man bash`:

```
-l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).
-c        If  the  -c  option  is  present,  then  commands  are read from the first non-option argument com‐
             mand_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, they are assigned to the  positional
             parameters, starting with $0.
```

Basically the stuff after the -c argument is a bash code and it will be executed.